# How to change if and for to assert in the test

Tags: java, unit-testing, for-loop, if-statement, junit

This test verifies the correctness of the method that transport planes receive from the list of military planes. As in the test not to use "for" and "if", and to use an assertTrue. Also can not use FLAG and lambda. Next to all this should be one Assert.

```
@Test
public void testGetTransportMilitaryPlanes() {
    Airport airport = new Airport(planes);
    List<MilitaryPlane> transportMilitaryPlanes = airport.getTransportMilitaryPlanes();

    boolean flag = false;
    for (MilitaryPlane militaryPlane : transportMilitaryPlanes) {
        if ((militaryPlane.getMilitaryType() == MilitaryType.TRANSPORT)) {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    Assert.assertEquals(flag, true);
}
```

I did so:

```
@Test
public void testGetTransportMilitaryPlanes() {
    Airport airport = new Airport(planes);
    List<MilitaryPlane> transportMilitaryPlanes = airport.getTransportMilitaryPlanes();

    MilitaryPlane militaryPlane = (MilitaryPlane) transportMilitaryPlanes;
    Assert.assertTrue(militaryPlane.getMilitaryType() == MilitaryType.TRANSPORT);

}
```

But the test fails like that. And in the original version was true.

Comment: Have you tried doing this using Stream API?

Comment: transportMilitaryPlanes include objects of MilitaryPlane and you are trying to cast this list to a single object. It is not true.

Comment: are you sure you don't need to test if ALL returned planes are of type TRANSPORT? The actual test will pass if just any one of the returned planes is of type TRANSPORT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using streams would make this much more elegant:

```
Assert.assertTrue
    (transportMilitaryPlanes.stream()
                            .anyMatch(p -> p.getMilitaryType() == MilitaryType.TRANSPORT));
```

Comment: @ernest_k yup, that's what the OP's original snippet does, just caught on to it now too, thanks for noticing (although, form the description in the text, it seems this logic may be incorrect, any `anyMatch` should have really been used).

Comment: Is there a solution without using lambdas?

Comment: @wanhels7ng you need some way to go over this list - either with a `for` loop, a `while` loop, a `do`-`while` loop or something. You could probably solve this problem with any of these, but that would be mincing semantics.